# MySQL 8 - Access denied when dropping procedures

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

On our MySQL 8.0.23 server, when a user tries to drop a procedure created by another user they get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1227
Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SYSTEM_USER privilege(s) for this operation
```

The user has the `DROP`, `CREATE ROUTINE`, and `ALTER ROUTINE` privileges. We did not have this issue with MySQL 5.7, but after migrating the data to a new MySQL 8 server, we are getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates the user trying to drop the procedure does not have the [`SYSTEM_USER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_system-user) privilege, which is required to drop procedures created by other users in **MySQL `8.0.23`**. The user can be granted this privilege **by an administrator with the `GRANT OPTION`**.

> In addition, ***if the definer of the routine has the `SYSTEM_USER`
> privilege, the user dropping it must also have this privilege.*** This is
> enforced in MySQL 8.0.16 and later.
>
> [Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-procedure.html)

You can do this by running the following command *as an administrator:*

```
GRANT SYSTEM_USER ON . TO 'user'@'host';
```

You can also ***check the current privileges*** of the user by running the following command:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'host';
```

**Another solution to consider,** if the user that created the procedure is no longer in-use and you would like to delete all the procedures created by that user, you can use the following command as an administrator:

```
DROP USER 'user'@'host';
```

***And another workaround solution*** to consider is to ensure the database object is created by account without the `SYSTEM_USER` privilege, then this is not an issue at all to deal with for other accounts without `SYSTEM_USER` privileges.

---

### Supporting Resources

- [13.7.1.6 `GRANT` Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html)
- [The `SYSTEM_USER` Dynamic Privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/the-system_user-dynamic-privilege/)

  > To modify users, you must have the `CREATE USER` privilege or the
  > `UPDATE` privilege on the mysql schema. We have added the
  > `SYSTEM_USER` dynamic privilege to make it possible to protect users
  > against the first case: modification by other users who have the
  > `CREATE USER` privilege. An account that has the `SYSTEM_USER`
  > privilege cannot be modified by an account that does not have
  > `SYSTEM_USER`, even if that account has `CREATE USER`.
  >
  > **How does the SYSTEM_USER privilege work?**
  >
  > The `SYSTEM_USER` privilege enforces the convention that if you are
  > modifying a user who is granted the `SYSTEM_USER` privilege, then in
  > addition to the privileges required to modify users, you also need to
  > have the `SYSTEM_USER` privilege. In other words, a user who has the
  > `SYSTEM_USER` and `CREATE USER` privileges can modify users who have
  > the `SYSTEM_USER` privilege.
- [13.7.1.5 `DROP USER` Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-user.html)

Comment: So in MySQL 8.0.23, the "DROP ROUTINE" privilege is no longer enough to drop procedures and all users must have SYSTEM_USER rights in order to perform this action? Will this then give them the right to change users? I want to give users the ability to create and drop procedures, but not to manage users.

Comment: Actually, I found it stated here: ["In addition, if the definer of the routine has the SYSTEM_USER privilege, the user dropping it must also have this privilege. This is enforced in MySQL 8.0.16 and later."](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-procedure.html) explicitly.

Comment: But will giving a user SYSTEM_USER privilege automatically give them the ability to manage other users as well? I see it says:
A system user can modify both system and regular accounts. That is, a user who has the appropriate privileges to perform a given operation on regular accounts is enabled by possession of SYSTEM_USER to also perform the operation on system accounts. A system account can be modified only by system users with appropriate privileges, not by regular users.

I assume "who has the appropriate priveleges" means that they must also have "CREATE USER", but it's not 100% clear

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/the-system_user-dynamic-privilege/

Comment: wow thanks so much - I've been trying to research this for months!

Answer (score 2):

Several changes were made in 8.0.16 wrt `SYSTEM_USER`.  Such as

> An account that has the SYSTEM_USER privilege can be specified as the DEFINER for a stored object only by users who have the SYSTEM_USER privilege, in addition to any other required privileges.

8.0.20:

> Privilege requirements were checked incorrectly for stored objects with a DEFINER that has the SYSTEM_USER privilege.

In general, 8.0 made many "little" changes to the privilege mechanism.  Check the manual, and accept that your processes may have to change.  Presumably the changes are for "the better".

Comment: Yeah I've been reading and re-reading the manual. MySQL docs in general aren't the most easy to understand...

Comment: Yeah.  Sometimes we can help you here.  I had to go looking -- I had not encountered that issue yet.